# How to clear JFrame when JButton is clicked to call/display the other JFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I have this code. When I run it, it displays a `JFrame` "menu" with two choices. When I click on a button it now displays the menu AND the new `JFrame` in the same window. And when I click on the other button, it adds with the existing things displayed on the same Window and adds and add inside. I'm thinking of using just one window/`JFrame`. How do I clear out the past `JFrame`? Is this possible?

```
package finals;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Finals extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel In1, In2, choice,menu;
    JTextField In, Inn, choicee, info, menuu, lol,loll;
    JButton PtoS, StoP,stop,ptos;
    public Finals(){

        setTitle("Menu");
        setSize(200,150);

        menu = new JLabel("Select a Program:");

        PtoS = new JButton("Proposition to Sentence");
        StoP = new JButton("Sentence to Proposition");

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        pane.add(menu);
        pane.add(PtoS);
        pane.add(StoP);

        PtoS.addActionListener(this);
        StoP.addActionListener(this);


        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(e.getSource() == StoP){

            setTitle("Sentence to Proposition");
            setSize(500,500);

            In1 = new JLabel("Enter First Sentence:", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            choice = new JLabel("Enter Operator:", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            In2 = new JLabel("Enter Second Sentence", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

            lol = new JTextField("[a]= AND [b]= OR [c]= NOT");
            lol.setEditable(false);
            loll = new JTextField();
            loll.setEditable(false);
            In = new JTextField();
            choicee = new JTextField();
            Inn = new JTextField();

            Container cont = getContentPane();
            cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

            cont.add(In1);
            cont.add(In);
            cont.add(lol);
            cont.add(loll);
            cont.add(choice);
            cont.add(choicee);
            cont.add(In2);
            cont.add(Inn);

            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == PtoS){

            setTitle("Proposition to Sentence");
            setSize(500,500);

            In1 = new JLabel("Enter p:", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            choice = new JLabel("Enter Operator:", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            In2 = new JLabel("Enter q:", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

            lol = new JTextField("[a]= AND [b]= OR [c]= NOT");
            lol.setEditable(false);
            loll = new JTextField();
            loll.setEditable(false);
            In = new JTextField();
            choicee = new JTextField();
            Inn = new JTextField();   

            Container cont = getContentPane();
            cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

            cont.add(In1);
            cont.add(In);
            cont.add(lol);
            cont.add(loll);
            cont.add(choice);
            cont.add(choicee);
            cont.add(In2);
            cont.add(Inn);

            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Finals X = new Finals();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)s.

Comment: It does not generate a new JFrame, when you click on any button. Instead, you generate a new container and add it to the exisiting page, without clearing anything out, change the Title and set a new size for the page. You should try to understand more how `JFrames` work. The `CardLayout` that resueman mentioned would be a good way to display several pages of your program.